# Combining JPA & Webflux for a SpringBoot application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I've built a spring boot project on JPA, Spring web. Now I want convert the microservice with JPA for models to achieve the @OneToMany, @OneToOne and I want to do the layers in a reactive way. Please help

I tried connecting the database using the spring.r2dbc.url = dburl but data is not fetching and throwing error on datasource url. Mydatabase is postgresql